# Where is the port number listed in this command result?

Tags: nmap, ports

I am running simple port scans on my system and I don't know if I am confused or not.

After running `lsof -i` and my results are:

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
firefox-e 8008 legion   43u  IPv4  96999      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:44376->ec2-34-212-188-196.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion   67u  IPv4  84170      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:52778->ord37s09-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion   94u  IPv4  93549      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:56526->ord37s35-in-f1.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion   98u  IPv4  89869      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:47874->ec2-52-86-133-10.compute-1.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  126u  IPv4  98838      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:40792->ord38s28-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  131u  IPv4  98839      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:41878->ord38s01-in-f10.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  133u  IPv4  88016      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:44998->server-99-84-167-136.ord52.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  176u  IPv4  88018      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:51574->ord37s18-in-f2.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  179u  IPv4  86297      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:46752->142.250.123.157:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  184u  IPv4  84401      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:40262->ord38s08-in-f2.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  187u  IPv4  92092      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:38700->ord38s28-in-f1.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  193u  IPv4  89558      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:40714->ord37s09-in-f2.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  199u  IPv4  90795      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:47760->136.144.59.88:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  201u  IPv4  90789      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:40586->server-99-84-253-65.ord50.r.cloudfront.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  210u  IPv4  90803      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:41732->lga15s49-in-f4.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  214u  IPv4  90805      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:45540->rio01s25-in-f3.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  221u  IPv4  97886      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:41752->ord37s07-in-f14.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
firefox-e 8008 legion  301u  IPv4  92423      0t0  TCP KryptL0c:59832->ord38s04-in-f2.1e100.net:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

On the first line, the port is 44376, correct?

If that is correct and these services are established on my system, why when I run a port scan with `nmap -p 1-65535 xxx.xxx.x.xxx` I get a result of no open ports?

Comment: "and these services are established on my system" -- those aren't services

Comment: if you want to view your listening ports in linux, I use `netstat -ntlup`, and on windows in powershell (elevated) `netstat -abno | findstr LISTENING`. Listening ports are ports established by applications for receiving unsolicited incoming traffic, like initial connection to a service.

Answer (score 3):

> On the first line, the port is 44376, correct?

Yes, the local port is 44376. However, you’re looking at an established connection between your system and a remote host. Having a connection on some port does not mean there is a listening socket on that port.

Here, because the local port is high (>40,000) and the remote port is 443 (HTTPS), we can infer with a high level of confidence that this is an outgoing connection to some HTTPS service on the internet.

I assume you’re on macOS or BSD.

Consider the following examples of actual listeners (the `-P` is so ports don’t get resolved to “known port names”):

```
$ lsof -i udp -P
…
syncthing 16758 fuzzy    7u  IPv6 0xd2b0d06f6f1a443d      0t0  UDP *:22000
…
```

```
$ lsof -i tcp -P
…
syncthing 16758 fuzzy   17u  IPv6 0xd2b0d06f70a57bfd      0t0  TCP *:22000 (LISTEN)
…
```

As you can see, they are easy to tell apart: They do not have remote endpoints. Because on TCP there is a proper “Listening” state, this is also explicitly listed. With UDP, things are not so easy.

If I were to run NMAP against TCP port 22000, it would report as open.

Answer (score 2):

```
KryptL0c:44376->ec2-34-212-188-196.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https
```

In this case we can *infer* that the connection points from the client host:port source of `KryptL0c:44376` to `->` the destination server host:port of `ec2-34-212-188-196.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:https`, because https is a known service.

Source ports are used for outbound, client-side connections, and do not have services listening on them, which is why they do not show as open. For example, every web browser connection to a web server will use a different client/source port to open the network connection. The port will be closed automatically when the connection is closed, and a new port will be used for the next connection. Source ports are generally high numbers, above 32768.

Also, common service port numbers are resolved into names like `https` (which is port 443) using the /etc/services file, and often may not appear as numbers in output like this.

Comment: The arrow is *always* from left to right, from local to remote, *that's all*. You cannot easily tell which side initiated the connection because after a TCP connection is established the two ends become peers. Even the existence or nonexistence of a local process listening on the given port cannot be a firm clue because the port may or may not have been listened on at the time the connection was established. When the local port is high (`52778`) and the remote port is well-known (`https`) then it's almost certain it's outbound. This is the only clue. The arrow itself tells *nothing* .